# Converge? $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right) }{k} $

Tags: convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series converges: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right) }{k} $$

I tired to use direct comparison test but since 1/k is not convergent, so I am not sure about in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**

Since you want a direct comparison use this inequality

$$\sin(x)\le x,\; \forall x\ge0$$

Answer (score 3):

It converges absolutely: $\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right| < \dfrac{1}{k}$

Answer (score 2):

It converges since it has positive terms and:
$$ \sin\dfrac1k \sim_{\infty}\frac1k,\enspace\text{hence}\enspace\frac{ \sin\frac1k }{k}\sim_{\infty}\frac1{k^2}.$$

Comment: It's useless to say that it converges **absolutely** since it's a **positive** series.

Comment: An old habit. It may happen the first terms of a series  are not positive., even if they're eventually positive.